# What are filtered field tags in Golang structs?

Tags: go

```
type User struct {
    Id                int
    Password          string `filtered:"true"`
}
```

Referring to the `filtered: "true"` part. Never seen this anywhere else, and can't find anything in the spec about it. Presumably it's similar to not exporting a field?

Does anyone have more information?

Comment: No, it's just a struct tag. Some package is making use of that, but it's not part of the language per say.

Comment: Okay, I see that now. They're checking the tag later and skipping it in the logs. Thanks @JimB, if you want to make that an answer I'll accept it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no special meaning assigned to struct tags by the language, they are interpreted by the package looking for them.

In this case, `filtered:true` means something to the package that uses the `User` type, and acts on that however it sees fit. This is the same as how the `json:` tags work in [`encoding/json`](https://golang.org/pkg/encoding/json/#Marshal).